# How do I override the core jquery file with the externally hosted jquery from google

Tags: php, jquery, yii, google-api

In Yii, currently all the dependancies for jquery are loading up a local version of jquery, which i believe is 1.6.*, un-minified.

Something along the lines of:

```
<script src="/assets/2343/js/jquery.js"></script>
```

I would like to update the core jquery dependancy to use the jquery 1.7.* from [google](https://developers.google.com/speed/libraries/devguide)

Basically I would like to include

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js">
```

at the bottom of all my pages whenever jquery is a dependancy.

Comment: Assuming you can't get into the code for some reason and just change the script tag?

Comment: the tag is automatically generated into the view by any component that requires 'jquery'. It's not possible to change the script tag.

Comment: @BenRowe: When it's too late, it's too late. Fix your code, or change the output before it's send to the browser.

Comment: Well, not so fast @hakre . I don't know anything about yii, but wordpress does the same thing (include jquery whenever it's a dependency), and there is a plugin that allows you to do the very thing the OP is asking. So there may be a way to do this with yii as well.

Comment: Solving that with what Yii offers = fix your code. Change the output before it's send to the browser = application agnostic way of solving the problem. FYI @JMCCreative

Comment: @BenRowe just to confirm: Am I right in thinking you aren't able to update the Yii code at all? You do not have access to the source code of this site?

Comment: Btw, the un-minified version of jquery is just when you have the YII_DEBUG flag set.  Yii automatically includes the minified version if you aren't debugging

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There's also another method [seen in yii's docs](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/topics.performance#minimizing-script-files):

> For example, we can include jquery.js from Google servers instead of our own server. To do so, we first configure the scriptMap as follows,

```
$cs=Yii::app()->clientScript;
$cs->scriptMap=array(
 'jquery.js'=>false,
 'jquery.ajaxqueue.js'=>false,
 'jquery.metadata.js'=>false,
 ......
);
```

> By mapping these script files to false, we prevent Yii from generating the code to include these files. Instead, we write the following code in our pages to explicitly include the script files from Google,

```
<head>
<?php echo CGoogleApi::init(); ?>

<?php echo CHtml::script(
 CGoogleApi::load('jquery','1.3.2') . "\n" .
 CGoogleApi::load('jquery.ajaxqueue.js') . "\n" .
 CGoogleApi::load('jquery.metadata.js')
 );
?>
......
</head>
```

Comment: That method seems to have stopped working at 1.1.16... too bad, i used it before for my own stuff and now i need to look up a new method. Sadface.

Comment: @IngwiePhoenix thanx for bringing this to my notice, i will investigate and update the answer, accordingly. thumbs up!

Answer (score 25):

After a bit more googling & looking around, I found the answer:

in the config, under 'components'

```
'clientScript'=>array(
  'packages'=>array(
    'jquery'=>array(
      'baseUrl'=>'http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/',
        'js'=>array('1.7.2/jquery.min.js'),
      )
    ),
  ),
),
```

Comment: +1, that looks good, there is another method listed in yii's docs, check my answer, however your method seems cleaner

Comment: @BenRowe: Including a link to what helped you would be very good for people who come across this answer in the future.

Comment: I love this answer, clean and reuse solution!

Comment: This is good if you want jquery to be included in all of your views. If you want this for a specific view only, it can be done like: `Yii::app()->clientScript->packages['jquery'] = array('baseUrl'=>'/js/jquery/', 'js'=>array('jquery-1.8.3.min.js'));` :)

Answer (score 2):

First Google hit: http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/259/serve-jquery-and-jquery-ui-from-google-s-cdn/

Next to overriding the clientScript configuration, you may also want to override the widgetFactory config:

```
  <?php
  return array(
  // other config
  'components'=>array(
    'clientScript'=>array(
      'packages'=>array(
        'jquery'=>array(
          'baseUrl'=>'//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/',
          'js'=>array('jquery.min.js'),
        )
      ),
      // other clientScript config
    ),
    'widgetFactory'=>array(
      'widgets'=>array(
        'CJui<WidgetName>'=>array( // where <WidgetName> is the name of the JUI Widget (Tabs, DatePicker, etc.). Each CJuiWidget used must be declared
          'scriptUrl'=>'//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1/',
          'theme'=>JUI-THEME,
          'themeUrl'=>'//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1/themes/',
        ),
        // Repeat for other CJuiWidgets
      ),
    ),
    // other component config
  ),
  // other config
);
```

Answer (score 0):

I know, this thread is rather old. But due to an encoutner I just had, I'd think it'd be important to mention this.

Somewhere in the latest releases of Yii, I fast-forwarded from 1.1.11 to current, a packages mechanism was not just implemented but improved. It had existed previously, but now it actually got to apoint, where the originally stated and ticked method of setting the jquery part to `false` would no longer work. Though, I found out how to fix it!

```
$cs->packages["jquery"] = [
    "basePath"=>Yii::app()->cdn->basePath,
    "baseUrl"=>Yii::app()->cdn->baseUrl,
    "js"=>["js/jquery-1.11.1.js"]
];
```

This is taken straight from my code, but illustrates how I did it. Basically, I added a jQuery entry to the packages list. When Core scripts are resolved, this list is searched up *before* the actual CoreScripts. Therefore, this will be picked up first and you can add your personal version of jQuery this way.

I hope it helps!